# Jquery escape #step unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I upgrade jquery from 2.14 to 2.2.0 and I always get an exception:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   li[data-target^=#step]

Code:

```
var count = $('li[data-target^=#step]').length;
```

Problem is with `#step`

How to escape it?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.2.0, it looks like you need to add quotes around the attribute's value when it contains the `#` character (it's worth pointing out that it works when the character `#` is removed).

```
var count = $('li[data-target^="#step"]').length;
```

See [these comments](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/#comment-553921) under the release notes. Apparently this was a bug fix.

Internally, jQuery will attempt to use the method `.querySelectorAll()`, which throws an error stating that `li[data-target^=#step]'` is not a valid selector, (which is why you need the quotes):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute `querySelectorAll` on `Document`: `li[data-target^=#step]` is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) you should use single quotes:

```
var count = $("li[data-target^='#step']").length;
```

Comment: I've never had a problem with either. If you look closer at the link provided, you'll see the header uses one format and the body another.